# Reusing Tableau Worksheets in a Dashboard

Tags: tableau-api

is there a way to reuse worksheet multiple times in a dashboard, perhaps by using parameter? I have a dashboard with 4 sheets, displaying similar thing (differs only on the data filtering).

Comment: No there isn't. Which is unfortunate, I've found many times I would like to do this.

Comment: You can't add the same sheet to another dashboard directly, but if you duplicate the dashboard that has the sheet you need you will get the same result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible. You cannot add the same worksheet to dashboard more than once.

Possibly workarounds:

- Duplicate the worksheets X number of times. This means you need to maintain multiple instances of the same worksheet if you need to make changes later.
- Implement the data filtering inside the single worksheet. Adding the field you would to filter by to the Columns or Rows will cause the data to be split up by that dimension.

Note that it advisable to minimize the number of worksheets on a dashboard for performance reasons. Therefore the latter workaround would be my first recommendation.